# How to update SwiftUI view with async data

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, concurrency

I am having trouble getting my data out of my async function and into my view. Setting a breakpoint in the ViewModel and then reading the data manually shows that it is in fact loading, but the view is now updating. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class CurrentUser {
    var id = ""
    var nickname = ""
}

class UserService {
    var currentUser = CurrentUser()
    static var shared = UserService()
    private init() {
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func fetchCurrentUser() async {
        let currentUser = UserService.shared.currentUser
    
        currentUser.id = "007"
        currentUser.nickname = "James Bond"
    
        // clearly I am missing something that would probably go here?
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    let currentUser = UserService.shared.currentUser

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("ID: \(currentUser.id)")
            Text("Nickname: \(currentUser.nickname)")
        }
        .task {
            await viewModel.fetchCurrentUser()
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using DispatchQueue and MainActor, but with no luck.

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code. I recommend following some SwiftUI tutorial to understand the flow of data, and also read about `@Published` properties of the ObservableObjects: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: SwiftUI is dependent on being told when to reload the `body` as of now your code isn't doing this. You need appropriate property wrappers. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) But as a tiny summary `class` needs to be an `ObservableObject` with `@Published` properties that is wrapped with an appropriate wrapper such as `StateObject` or `ObservedObject`. Since you are starting I would stay away from `class` until you get more familiar use `struct`

Comment: Agree there are many things wrong. It's important you learn that the View struct is a view model already and better than an object. You need to learn structs to use SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. The view probably should not be interacting with the `UserService` directly. The view model should be doing that.
2. The view model should fetch the user from the user service and update its own `@Published` property that the view is observing. (And I used the `@MainActor` so it publishes accounts for the view on the main thread.)

A couple of unrelated observations:

3. I probably would make `CurrentUser` (which I renamed to just `User` in my example below) a `struct`. We generally prefer value types for model types (though you should feel free to use reference type if you really need shared state).
4. Rather than having a user whose `id` and `nickname` are `""`, I would use an `Optional` value. We generally like to avoid having random sentinel values.

So, I might suggest something like:

```swift
struct User {
    let id: String
    let nickname: String
}

actor UserService {
    var currentUser: User?

    static let shared = UserService()

    private init() { }

    func fetchCurrentUser() async throws -> User {
        guard let currentUser else {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))              // let's simulate a slow initial request

            let user = User(id: "007", nickname: "James Bond")
            currentUser = user

            return user
        }

        return currentUser
    }
}

@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    @Published var error: Error?

    func fetchCurrentUser() async {
        do {
            currentUser = try await UserService.shared.fetchCurrentUser()
        } catch {
            self.error = error
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            if let error = viewModel.error {
                Text("Whoops: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            if let user = viewModel.currentUser {
                Text("ID: \(user.id)")
                Text("Nickname: \(user.nickname)")
            } else {
                Text("Not logged in")
            }
        }
        .task {
            await viewModel.fetchCurrentUser()
        }
    }
}
```

In my example above, I assumed that the fetch of the user might be asynchronous. We do not have enough information about your business logic to know whether that is relevant here. But do not get lost in these details.

The idea is merely that (a) the view model interacts with services, not the view; and (b) the view model is the one with the `@Published` properties.